# Error Building Substrate contract Node(error[E0603]: module `group` is private) After switching Substrate dependencies to "polkadot-v0.9.23"

Tags: polkadot, substrate-contracts-node

So, I am trying to point all my dependencies on substrate contract node to the stable branch `polkadot-v0.9.23`

But I get these errors when i try compiling

```
error[E0603]: module `group` is private
   --> /Users/Damilare/.cargo/git/checkouts/substrate-7e08433d4c370a21/76522d7/frame/support/procedural/tools/src/syn_ext.rs:50:53
    |
50  |                 let syn::group::$name { token, content } = syn::group::$parse(input)?;
    |                                                                 ^^^^^ private module
    |
note: the module `group` is defined here
   --> /Users/Damilare/.cargo/registry/src/github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823/syn-1.0.98/src/lib.rs:304:1
    |
304 | mod group;
    | ^^^^^^^^^^

error[E0603]: module `group` is private
   --> /Users/Damilare/.cargo/git/checkouts/substrate-7e08433d4c370a21/76522d7/frame/support/procedural/tools/src/syn_ext.rs:50:14
    |
50  |                 let syn::group::$name { token, content } = syn::group::$parse(input)?;
    |                          ^^^^^ private module
    |
note: the module `group` is defined here
   --> /Users/Damilare/.cargo/registry/src/github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823/syn-1.0.98/src/lib.rs:304:1
    |
304 | mod group;
    | ^^^^^^^^^^
```

Comment: Please include your Github repo link here. Also, it looks like the releases are maintained by tags: https://github.com/paritytech/substrate-contracts-node/tags

Answer (score 2):

For better old version compatibility.

```
cargo update -p syn --precise 1.0.96
```

I'm on polkadot-v0.9.23 too. And I don't want to change my stable toolchain. This could be the best option.

Answer (score 1):

I synchronized [`substrate-contracts-node`](https://github.com/paritytech/substrate-contracts-node) with the latest Substrate yesterday. There were some minor changes necessary for the latest Substrate release. Could be that this solves your problem.

This is the toolchain which I used locally:

```
rustc 1.64.0-nightly (2643b1646 2022-07-27)
```

Could you try pointing the dependencies in there to the Polkadot release that you want to use?

If it doesn't work:

- What command are you executing for the build?
- What's your local toolchain?
- Are you using the latest `HEAD` of the `substrate-contracts-node` repository?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried changing the Rust compiler version using rustup command? That could fix your problem or maybe not

Comment: same problem here. Using the following branch of the substrate node for the runtime: polkadot-v0.9.23.