# How to solve this Failed to compact generated WASM binary.: Error(UnknownOpcode(192))

Tags: substrate-node-template, polkadot, rust, build

For one assignment I have run the command `cargo build --release` so that I can build the pallet. After that I was getting the error[image]

After that according to this-  [Error Building Substrate contract Node(error[E0603]: module `group` is private) After switching Substrate dependencies to "polkadot-v0.9.23"](https://substrate.stackexchange.com/questions/3479/error-building-substrate-contract-nodeerrore0603-module-group-is-private)
I have used the command `cargo update -p syn@1.0.109 --precise 1.0.96`
I have used `syn@1.0.109` as I have two syn as in image.[image]
**After that I was getting this error**[image]

Can anyone help me in that.

Comment: https://substrate.stackexchange.com/questions/7881/error-loading-of-original-wasm-failed

Comment: Does this answer your question? [cannot run substrate on a fresh macbook m2](https://substrate.stackexchange.com/questions/7714/cannot-run-substrate-on-a-fresh-macbook-m2)

Comment: please copy your errors as text instead of images so it is possible to copy and paste from it